# How to split string after certain length and update the remaining string in different column

Tags: sql-server

Column has value

```
'Allianz General Insurance Company (Malaysia) Berhad Test Test Test Test TesT'..
```

Update  **col1** with length upto **70** characters and update  **col2** with remaining characters.
Ex:

```
**Col1**= 'Allianz General Insurance Company (Malaysia) Berhad'


**Col2**= 'Test Test Test Test TesT'
```

Comment: please follow this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to ask a question properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Select Case when LEN(ColumnName)>70 then SUBSTRING(ColumnName, 0, 70)   as Col1,Case when LEN(ColumnName)>70 then SUBSTRING(ColumnName, 71, 140)  end as Col2   :::::Value: Col1= 'Allianz General Insurance Company (Malaysia) Berhad'Col2='Test Test Test Test TesT'
```